# Portable database driven web app

Tags: database, html

I'm trying to create a standalone HTML5 document that utilizes SQlite or some other database software for a GTD-like to do list. I want to save the database in the same directory as the html file so that I can access the data on a usb stick from any computer.

Is there a way to save the database to the html file's local directory?  Otherwise, is there a solution such that an HTML5 app (existing in a single html file) can truly be portable on USB, database and all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqlite database is resident on the computer/device that runs the page. You can roll the markup, the static content, the javascript to control it and the css to style it into a single HTML page, but you can't embed the database.

I would suggest you would be better off looking at a remote database that you can sync with a local copy for off-line usage. But this is very well-trodden ground. There are no shortage of apps out there doing exactly this.